# Fastest way to get total count of employees , total count of employees who are absent in each department?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005, rdbms

**Department**

```
+-------+------------+
| EmpId | DepId|
+-------+------------+
|     1 | IT         |
|     2 | admin      |
|     3 | IT         |
|     4 | IT         |
|     5 | admin      |
+-------+------------+
```

**Attendance**

```
+-------+--------+
| EmpId | Status |
+-------+--------+
|     1 | P      |
|     2 | P      |
|     3 | P      |
|     4 | A      |
|     5 | P      |
+-------+--------+
```

**Desired Output :**

```
+-------+------------+--------------+
| DepId | TotalCount | PresentCount |
+-------+------------+--------------+
| Admin |          2 |            2 |
| IT    |          3 |            2 |
+-------+------------+--------------+
```

**My Query:**

```
 SELECT DepId,
       COUNT(att.empid) total,
       sum(CASE WHEN status = 'P' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) presetCount
FROM attendance att
INNER JOIN departments dep ON att.empid=dep.empid
GROUP BY DepId
```

Can this be optimized further? if yes how?

Comment: What's wrong with your query? does it takes long to run?

Comment: @Yossi it kinda does. Tables are huge, lots of departments and employees.

Comment: Are this table indexed? I can't think of a way to optimize this further

Comment: @Yossi They will be on production. I was just wondering if there is a better way of doing this.

Comment: If it already works and you only seek for improvement, have you considered trying http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: @T3H40 I was not even aware of codereview, thanks. +1

Answer (score 0):

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.departments', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE dbo.departments
GO
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.attendance', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE dbo.attendance
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.departments (EmpId INT PRIMARY KEY, DepId VARCHAR(10))
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.departments
VALUES (1, 'IT'), (2, 'admin'), (3, 'IT'), (4, 'IT '), (5, 'admin')
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.attendance (EmpId INT PRIMARY KEY, [Status] CHAR(1))
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.attendance
VALUES (1, 'P'), (2, 'P'), (3, 'P'), (4, 'A'), (5, 'P')
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ix ON dbo.departments (DepId)
GO

SELECT
     DepId
   , COUNT_BIG(1) AS total
   , COUNT_BIG(att.EmpId) AS presetCount
FROM departments dep
LEFT JOIN attendance att ON att.empid = dep.EmpId AND att.[status] = 'P'
GROUP BY DepId
```

My execution plan:

[image]

Your execution plan:

[image]

Output -

```
DepId      total                presetCount
---------- -------------------- -------------
admin      2                    2
IT         3                    2
```

Comment: Output is incorrect. It shows total count in both columns even though there are some employees who are absent

Comment: In this case please provide a example... when this query return incorrect results

Comment: Ignore my previous comment. Your query is working fine. Many thanks. 
47% to 18% is a significant improvement. It would be just perfect if you could write some explanation  to your post.

Comment: Index is needed to avoid a sort operation... filter in `LEFT JOIN` 
may reduce logical reads from `attendance`

Answer (score 0):

Because you are comparing performance, I would suggest also trying `APPLY`:

```
 SELECT DepId, a.total, a.presentCount
FROM departments dep OUTER APPLY
     (SELECT COUNT(*) as total, 
             SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'P' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as presentCount
      FROM attendance att
      WHERE att.empid = dep.empid
     ) a;
```

Then, be sure you have an index on `attendance(empid, status)`.

I'm not saying this is faster (it depends on the size of data and other considerations).  But it is worth checking because it gets around the outer aggregation.

Note:  checking performance on small sets of data is often meaningless.  The execution plans and performance characteristics depend heavily on the size of the data.